# Expected value of two dependent random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Suppose $f_{X,Y} (x, y) = 3/14*(xy + x) , \space 0 ≤ x ≤ 2, \space0 ≤ y ≤ x$

Find $E[XY]$.

How do you find the expected value of two random variables like this? I know the properties of E[X] but I never studied E[XY].

Do I just assume they are independant? It doesn't look like it, because $f_X(x) * f_Y(y)$ does not equal $f_{X,Y}$...

Comment: Just find the RHS of $\mathbb EXY=\int\int xyf_{X,Y}(x,y)dxdy$.

Comment: @drhab oh. That makes sense

Answer (score 2):

As [drhab](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/75923/drhab) mentioned, the answer is simply:

$EXY=∫∫xyf_{X,Y}(x,y)dxdy$.